# NPE in WaypointMissionOperator.checkParameters with DJI Matrice 100 or 600

Tags: dji-sdk

## UPDATE

Trying to load a waypoint mission with the [Android SDK sample](https://github.com/dji-sdk/Mobile-SDK-Android) updated to version 4.11 results in an internal Null Pointer Exception

**Prerequisites:**

- An android phone installed with the sample SDK updated to 4.11
- A Matrice 100 / 600 connected to the DJI Assistant 2

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. Open the sample SDK
2. Click "Open" after the drone connects
3. Click "New Waypoint Mission Operator"
4. Click "Load"
5. App crashes with the following stack

```
com.dji.sdk.sample E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.dji.sdk.sample, PID: 14107
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.Object java.util.Map.get(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
    at dji.common.mission.waypoint.Waypoint.checkParameters(Unknown Source:15)
    at dji.common.mission.MissionUtils.checkEachWaypointValid(Unknown Source:18)
    at dji.common.mission.MissionUtils.checkWaypointMissionParameters(Unknown Source:44)
    at dji.common.mission.waypoint.WaypointMission$Builder.checkParameters(Unknown Source:10)
    at dji.internal.mission.abstraction.waypoint.WaypointMissionAbstraction.a(Unknown Source:0)
    at dji.sdk.mission.waypoint.WaypointMissionOperator.loadMission(Unknown Source:32)
    at com.dji.sdk.sample.demo.missionoperator.WaypointMissionOperatorView.onClick(:107)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6310)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24970)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:794)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6662)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
```

---

## Original Question

The same code works perfectly on the P4A but fails on the Matrice 100 / 600.

Here are the relevant parts of my code in Kotlin.

1. Create a list of waypoints.

```
val waypointList: List<Waypoint> = data.points.map {
    val waypoint = Waypoint(it.latitude, it.longitude, it.altitude)
    waypoint.speed = 3
    waypoint.heading = 0
    waypoint.gimbalPitch = 0
    waypoint.turnMode = WaypointTurnMode.CLOCKWISE

    waypoint.actionRepeatTimes = 1
    waypoint.actionTimeoutInSeconds = 3
    waypoint.cornerRadiusInMeters = 1
    waypoint
}
```

2. Create a WaypointMission.Builder Object

```
val mission = WaypointMission.Builder()
    .waypointList(waypointList)
    .waypointCount(waypointList.size)
    .autoFlightSpeed(10)
    .repeatTimes(1)
    .setGimbalPitchRotationEnabled(false)
    .setExitMissionOnRCSignalLostEnabled(false)
    .finishedAction(WaypointMissionFinishedAction.NO_ACTION)
    .maxFlightSpeed(13)
    .flightPathMode(WaypointMissionFlightPathMode.CURVED)
    .headingMode(WaypointMissionHeadingMode.AUTO)
    .gotoFirstWaypointMode(WaypointMissionGotoWaypointMode.POINT_TO_POINT)
```

3. mission.[checkParameters()](https://developer.dji.com/api-reference/android-api/Components/Missions/DJIWaypointMission.html?search=checkparameters&i=1&#djiwaypointmission_checkparameters_inline)
4. WaypointOperator.loadMission(mission.build())
5. WaypointOperator.uploadMission()

With the P4A: the code continues with no error, and goes off to the waypoint mission.
With Matrice 100, the `checkParameters` function in step 3 returns no result and the code just stalls here with the `WaypointOperator.currentState` staying at `READY_TO_UPLOAD`

I have tried everything in the last 2 days, and the only thing I can guess is that I am missing some parameter that the Matrice 100 needs, but I have no clue what that might be, and can't find anything in the documentation about it.

Comment: Just checked the Matrice 600, and it also doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bug on DJI's part, but they offered me a temporary solution until the next version is released.

```
After confirming, this problem only occurs when your aircraft is not mounting the camera.

So, for the temporary workaround, you can mount a camera on your drone when you using v4.11.
Also, this issue will be fixed in the coming v4.11.1 official release.
```